# Directories are listed twice

Tags: shell-script, ls, newlines

I have something odd. 
I creates some directories using a very simple script :

... create all directories ( running under a user that has the correct rights )
e.g :

```
mkdir -p /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/ISU2EAI/VEA/tre
```

But I get the directories double ! 
When I do `ls -lrt` I get

```
uxel081c: wmb - /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/EAI2ISU/VEA # ls -lrt
total 0

drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jan 28 15:25 tre
drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jan 28 15:25 err
drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jan 28 15:25 arc
drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jun 12 08:35 tre
drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jun 12 08:35 tbt
drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jun 12 08:35 err
drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jun 12 08:35 arc
drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb      mqbrkrs         256 Jun 13 10:49 tbt
```

(notice the double **tre, tbt , arc** ... )

They double directories do point to the same data.

When you do a normal `ls` you get

```
uxel081c: wmb - /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/EAI2ISU/VEA # ls
    tre  tre
```

Thus only two directories !

What happens ?

Comment: Welcome on StackExchange. Could you post the whole script you use to create the directories, please? The problem probably is there, unless ls and mkdir have strange behaviour on your system (due to aliases, for example). Also, could you post the output of `ls -lrti`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply !
Two more points that I need to mention 

a) This is a NAS share  - thus not a local drive)
b) The directories existed already  ( manually manualy) prior to executing the script.  
   Nevertheless this is a way of working and it is only now that we see an issue.

Comment: The outcome from lrti
 wmb - /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/EAI2ISU/VEA # ls -lrti
total 0
98332 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jan 28 15:25 tre
98333 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jan 28 15:25 err
98334 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jan 28 15:25 arc
98802 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jun 12 08:35 tre
98801 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jun 12 08:35 tbt
98800 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jun 12 08:35 err
98799 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jun 12 08:35 arc
98331 drwxr-xr-x    2 wmb  mqbrkrs 256 Jun 13 10:49 tbt

Comment: My script ( be dazzled)mkdir -p /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/EAI2ISU/VEA/arc
mkdir -p /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/EAI2ISU/VEA/err
mkdir -p /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/EAI2ISU/VEA/tbt
mkdir -p /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/EAI2ISU/VEA/tre

Comment: When I said "post this or that", I meant "update your question". It's quite difficult to read code when it's not properly formatted and indented :).

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a local drive?

Answer (score 2):

If I had to hazard a guess I'd be suspicious of the files and whether they have non-printable characters in their names. You can display these special characters through the use of the following switches to `ls`.

*excerpt from [Removing Non-printing Characters from File Names](http://www.arsc.edu/arsc/support/howtos/nonprintingchars/)*

```
Locating "non-printing" characters in file names

The ls command has all the options you need to detect "hidden" characters:

Command      Function                                         Sample Output
-------      --------                                         ------ ------
ls           hides/interprets nongraphic characters           zzz
ls -b        prints octal codes for nongraphic characters     zzz\010\010\010aaa
ls -q        prints question marks for nongraphic characters  zzz???aaa
```

See the above referenced page for more information on these types of characters and there removable.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you edited your script on Windows at some point, and that version had [Windows line endings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems): a CR (carriage return) followed by a LF (line feed). As far as Unix shells are converned, LF is the line ending character, and CR is an ordinary character. So if you have this in your script (where ␍ is a CR character):

```
mkdir -p /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/ISU2EAI/VEA/tre␍
```

then in your editor you'll only see

```
mkdir -p /home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/ISU2EAI/VEA/tre
```

but the shell sees that the `mkdir` command is called with the arguments `-p` and `/home/EAI003A/05_EDSNFE/ISU2EAI/VEA/tre␍`.

When the CR character is printed onto a terminal, its effect is to move the cursor to the beginning of the line. With `ls -l`, CR only turns up at the end of the line and so has no visible effect. With plain `ls`, the `CR` at the end of every second file name causes the next pair of file names to overwrite the previous lines.

Convert your script to use Unix line endings with one of these commands:

```
dos2unix /path/to/script                # if dos2unix is available
sed -i -e $'s/\r//' /path/to/script     # on Linux or Cygwin only
perl -i -e 's/\r$//' /path/to/script
```

Your editor may have a way to do that, too. In your editor, when you edit a shell script, check that the line endings are “LF” or “Unix” or “Linux” and not “CRLF” or “Windows” or ”DOS“.

Depending on your unix variant, try `ls -b` or `ls -Q` or `ls -q` to make the special character in the file name appear. To merge the two directories, first move the files into the proper directory, then remove the other one.

```
mv -i tre/* tre?/
rmdir tre?/
```