# Pass a list of URLs contained in a file to curl

Tags: command-line, files, curl

I have to set ACL on a multiple files. 
I have downloaded a list of object stored using below commands.

```
C:\Users\Gshrivastava\Downloads\curl_748_0>curl  -o urlname.csv -i -k -H "Authorization: HCP bXFl:29def7dbc8892a9389ebc7a5210dd844" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept:application/xml" -d @mqe.xml "http://tenant.hcp3.hdsblr.com/query?prettyprint
```

I have then sorted url names into a text file .

```
ns.tenant.hcp3.hdsblr.com/rest/pic/Cat/images.jpg 
ns.tenant.hcp3.hdsblr.com/rest/pic/Cat/6.png 
ns.tenant.hcp3.hdsblr.com/rest/pic/landscape/9.png 
ns.tenant.hcp3.hdsblr.com/rest/pic/landscape/5.png
```

content of text file >

Now I want to use this file as argument or variable so that all the filenames are set with ACL.

```
curl.exe -k http://ns.tenant.hcp3.hdsblr.com/rest/ACL/filename.ext/?type=acl -i -H "Authorization: HCP YWRtaW4=:29def7dbc8892a9389ebc7a5210dd844" -T acl.xml
```

Comment: Looks like you're on Windows? Try the SuperUser SE, you're on the Linux site here :)

Comment: I hope this isn't your real authorization cookie here!

Answer (score 18):

If I understand correctly, you have a file containing a list of URLs (one per line), and you want to pass those URLs to CURL.

There are two main ways to do that: with [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs), or with [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). With `xargs`:

```
xargs <urls.txt curl …
```

With command substitution:

```
curl … $(cat urls.txt)
```

Both methods mangle some special characters, but given what characters are valid in URLs, this shouldn't be an issue, except that with `xargs`, single quotes (`'`) need to be encoded as `%27`. Alternatively, use `xargs -l`.

Note that since this is a Unix site, I'm assuming that you're running a Unix variant and invoking these commands from a Unix shell such as bash. Given that you're running `curl.exe`, you appear to be using Windows. If you're going to use Unix tools, I recommend that you do so from a Unix shell such as bash or zsh; Windows does not come with `xargs` any more than it comes with `curl`, and `cmd` does not have command substitution (at least not in the same form). There is probably a way to do this with Windows tools, but I don't know what it is and it's off-topic here.

Also, if you're using Unix tools under Windows, take care that your list of URLs uses Unix line endings (LF only), not Windows line endings (CR+LF). Unix tools expect a line to end with LF and treat CR as an ordinary character. For more information, see [Directories are listed twice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79688/directories-are-listed-twice/79721#79721) and many other questions on this site.

Comment: (offtopic but) [as of 2017 Windows 10 does have curl.exe](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/containers/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/ba-p/382409) -- but still not xargs or command substitution. Plus W10 powershell _aliases_ `curl` to `Invoke-WebRequest` which is crudely similar but decidedly not the same.

Comment: I used `curl -O $(cat files.txt)` with files.txt listing 4 image files, one per line. The first file on the list downloaded fine, but all the subsequent ones failed in that the output was on stdout instead of being downloaded. None of the image URLs had any special characters, just alphanumeric, colon, slash, dash and underscore.

Comment: @AlexIxeras I had the same problem and found a solution using --remote-name-all like this `curl --remote-name-all $(cat files.txt)`

Answer (score 13):

This command
`xargs -n 1 curl -O < urls.txt`

by [ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865929/11451863)

Answer (score 8):

curl has the -K options where you can pass multiple urls, reads from a file that has this format:

```
url = url1
# Uncomment if you want to download the file 
# output = "file1"
# Uncomment if your sysadmin only allows well known User Agent 
# user-agent = "Mozilla/5.0"
```

Also you can use xargs (wget - i style)

```
$ xargs -a urls.txt -I{} curl -# -O {}
```

urls.txt format:

```
https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/LATEST.tar.gz
https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.16.tar.gz.sig
```

Using HEREDOC

```
curl -# -K - <<URL
    url = "https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.16.tar.gz"
    output = "libsodium-1.0.16.tar.gz"

    url = "https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.16.tar.gz.sig"
   output="libsodium-1.0.16.tar.gz.sig"
URL
```

[Reference](https://www.librebyte.net/en/internet-browsers/as-download-files-using-curl/)

Comment: > reads from a file that has this format
It'd be nice if you could give an example with more than one set of inputs. It isn't 100% clear how curl delimits the different sets of options...is it anything between a 'url=' and the next one (or eof)?

Comment: The -Z option can be combined with -K - to read lots of URLs from a file and download them a lot more quickly than running multiple curl commands...needs curl v7.70.0 or greater.

Comment: @MaxWaterman every url config should be in its own line that is enough.

Comment: @Max Waterman Thank you for the -Z option very useful for mass file download.

Comment: > every url config should be in its own line that is enough < yeah, but what about the other command line options - do they need to be duplicated, or specified separately (if they're different for each URL), or what?

Answer (score 7):

Gilles' solution didn't work for me, so I created a loop solution. One `curl` call per line.

```
# for looking at the commands first.
$ cat urls.txt | while read f; do echo curl "${f}" -O; done;

# remove echo when you feel safe.
$ cat urls.txt | while read f; do curl "${f}" -O; done;
```

**UPDATE:** As requested, an attempt to improve performance with a single `curl` call:

```
$ cat urls.txt | while read f; do echo -e "url = \"${f}\"\n-O\n" >> config; done;
$ curl -K config
```

Comment: It's a bit inefficient to do one curl per line, imo. Can you make one that uses the '-K -' option?

Comment: Can also use `sed` to eliminate the need for an intermediate config file: `sed -E 's/(.+)/url="\1"\n-O/' urls.txt | curl -K -` (or `… | curl -ZK -` for parallel downloads)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're on Windows and are using a CMD Prompt. The above example assume you have a linux environment. But in case you're wanting to do this in your CMD Prompt, create a batch file (such as `mycurlscript.bat`) and put this in it:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (urls.txt) do curl.exe -k %%A -i -H "Authorization: HCP YWRtaW4=:29def7dbc8892a9389ebc7a5210dd844" -T acl.xml
```

Then save your list of urls you want to download into a file named `urls.txt`. Put these into the same directory as your `acl.xml` file and from your CMD Prompt run: `mycurlscript.bat`